# Google Glass - Not receving subscription notifications -

Tags: .net, google-glass, google-mirror-api

Can someone spot what is wrong? the callback url is a valid ssl url. Also how do we know if google service itself is having issues? I don't yet see posts to my callback url at all on my web server logs..

I don't seem to be getting notifications back.

```
        StoredCredentialsDBContext db = new StoredCredentialsDBContext();

        TimelineItem item = new TimelineItem()
        {
            Creator=new Contact(){DisplayName="DLN Reply Card",Id="TESTREPLYCARD" },
            Title = Test Number",
            Text = "Say Test Number",
            Notification = new NotificationConfig() { Level = "DEFAULT" }

        };

        Google.Apis.Mirror.v1.Data.MenuItem menuItem=new Google.Apis.Mirror.v1.Data.MenuItem();
        menuItem.Action="REPLY";

        item.MenuItems = new List<Google.Apis.Mirror.v1.Data.MenuItem>();
        item.MenuItems.Add(menuItem);

        foreach (StoredCredentials creds in db.StoredCredentialSet)
        {
            AuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState()
            {
                AccessToken = creds.AccessToken,
                RefreshToken = creds.RefreshToken
            };
            MirrorService service = new MirrorService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                Authenticator = Utils.GetAuthenticatorFromState(state)
            });
            item.IsPinned = true;
            Subscription subscription = new Subscription();
            subscription.Collection = "timeline";
            subscription.VerifyToken = "XXXXX";
            subscription.UserToken = creds.UserId;
            subscription.Operation = new List<String>();
            subscription.Operation.Add("INSERT");
            subscription.Operation.Add("UPDATE");
            subscription.CallbackUrl = "https://changedthename.com/GG/Notify";

            Subscription t=service.Subscriptions.Insert(subscription).Fetch();

            TimelineItem i=service.Timeline.Insert(item).Fetch();

            SubscriptionsListResponse r= service.Subscriptions.List().Fetch();


        }
```

The output of executing Fetch() which is subscription object (I just hid the domain name):

```
 ?t
{Google.Apis.Mirror.v1.Data.Subscription}
    CallbackUrl: "https://changedname.com/GG/Notify"
    Collection: "timeline"
    ETag: null
    Id: "timeline"
    Kind: "mirror#subscription"
    Notification: null
    Operation: Count = 2
    Updated: "2014-02-06T16:59:25.642Z"
    UserToken: "XXXXXXXXXX"
    VerifyToken: "XXXXX"
```

Item I used:

```
 ?i
{Google.Apis.Mirror.v1.Data.TimelineItem}
    Attachments: null
    BundleId: null
    CanonicalUrl: null
    Created: "2014-02-06T16:59:32.729Z"
    Creator: {Google.Apis.Mirror.v1.Data.Contact}
    DisplayTime: null
    ETag: "1391705972729"
    Html: null
    HtmlPages: null
    Id: "73b75493-3371-4b2c-856d-df8674b54ede"
    InReplyTo: null
    IsBundleCover: null
    IsDeleted: null
    IsPinned: false
    Kind: "mirror#timelineItem"
    Location: null
    MenuItems: Count = 1
    Notification: {Google.Apis.Mirror.v1.Data.NotificationConfig}
    PinScore: null
    Recipients: null
    SelfLink: "https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/timeline/73b75493-3371-4b2c-856d-df8674b54ede"
    SourceItemId: null
    SpeakableText: null
    Text: "Say Test Number"
    Title: "Test Number"
    Updated: "2014-02-06T16:59:32.729Z"


?r
{Google.Apis.Mirror.v1.Data.SubscriptionsListResponse}
    ETag: null
    Items: Count = 1
    Kind: "mirror#subscriptionsList"
```

My Test payload for my callback url using SOapui

Post req with following payload

```
{
  "collection": "timeline",
  "itemId": "d45fcc3a-4346-453a-8783-88667a002387",
  "operation": "UPDATE",
  "userToken": "XXXXXXX",
  "verifyToken": "XXXXX",
  "userActions": [
    {
      "type": "<TYPE>",
      "payload": "<PAYLOAD>"
    }
  ]
}
```

200 ok response back from soapui

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 04 Feb 2014 17:48:47 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm making a couple of assumptions:

1. You are seeing the cards posted to your Glass.
2. You're using .NET

Offhand, I'm not aware of any way to make sure the Mirror service is working correctly - but every time I've suspected a problem with it, it has turned out to be my service. A few things to try:

1. Make sure your callback URL actually works, accepts POST commands, and responds with HTTP code 200. You're correctly using HTTPS, but make sure you can get to the site using curl or wget with a POST operation, not just a GET operation. Test it from a machine outside the domain you're on to make sure the hostname is being looked up correctly and that you're not being blocked by firewalls.
2. You may want to do the subscription before you add the timeline item - best practice is to issue the subscription once when the person first logs in. I don't think this is it, but I can see it as possible that the subscription ends up not being applied correctly for some reason.
3. Test to make sure the Item and Subscription are correctly entered on the server - examine what is returned by both commands to make sure they are correct or issue a service.Subscriptions.List().Fetch() and examine the results.

**Update**: Based on what you've posted as the results of the Subscription.Insert().Fetch(), something seems odd there. The ETag and Id should certainly NOT be null. Something seems incorrect about about the Subscription insert attempt.

You may want to try a Subscriptions.List().Fetch() and see if there are any subscriptions actually registered.

**Update 2**: I would still suggest you do one, or both, of the following:

1. Replace your subscription code with the code provided in the .NET example at https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/subscriptions/insert#examples and call it. I don't know enough about .NET, but there may be a reason your code is causing problems, since it appears that you the result of the Fetch() call is not a valid Subscription.
2. Implement the method in the .NET example at https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/subscriptions/list#examples and call it after you do the create. If no subscription is listed, this is further indication you are not creating it for some reason.

Comment: yes I can see the reply card and I am using .net. Do u see anything wrong in the code itself? I can reply and it says card sent. Afterwards I don't even see a request in web server logs at all for callback url

Comment: Nothing jumped out as a code problem to me. Did you try any of the three things I suggested?

Comment: "Prisoner" Thank You for the follow up. Here is where I am  with this whole things. I am inclining to think something with Google mirror service not able to trust Go Daddy G2 ssl cert (I could be wrong) Here is what I have going'

Comment: I used soapui to generate a post request to my callback url and was able to successful post andf received 200 ok and infact my notify code wrote back to glaSS

Comment: Post req with following payload

{
  "collection": "timeline",
  "itemId": "d45fcc3a-4346-453a-8783-88667a002387",
  "operation": "UPDATE",
  "userToken": "XXXXXXX",
  "verifyToken": "XXXXX",
  "userActions": [
    {
      "type": "<TYPE>",
      "payload": "<PAYLOAD>"
    }
  ]
}


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Comment: This thing is driving me nuts :) how would we know Google is experiencing cert trust issues or not with Go Daddy G2 SSL certs? When we renewed the certs I had ton of Java clients of totally a different app who had to manaull trust the Go daddy G2 ssl cert

Comment: I don't think this is a SSL trust issue. I repeat - did you try my suggestions 2 and 3 above?

Comment: yes I tried 2 and 3 as well. here is why I thought it mioght be an ssl issue when we got this new ssl cert we have had issues with java clients not trusing Go Daddy g2 ssl certs

Comment: subscription output subscription
{Google.Apis.Mirror.v1.Data.Subscription}
    CallbackUrl: "https://mygodaddyg2certdomain/GG/Notify"
    Collection: "timeline"
    ETag: null
    Id: null
    Kind: null
    Notification: null
    Operation: Count = 2
    Updated: null
    UserToken: "XXXXXXXXXX"
    VerifyToken: "XXXXX"

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the output? (Sorry, it is just difficult to read as a comment, and it is relevant info in the question)

Comment: Thank You so much. I have updated with what you requested. unfortunately I did not pout in real domain. do u need it? may be I can email u

Comment: Is Subscription id and etag supposed to be null?

Comment: When you create the Subscription, they should be null, but when returned to you after being created, they should be populated. This strongly suggests that there is a problem while creating them. Answer updated, and I strongly suggest you do one or both of my suggestions to try and figure out what might be happening.

Comment: thank you. after subscription is created my etag is still null and id now says "timeline".

Comment: Please update your question to show what you are doing, exactly. This makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Is ther eanyaway I can email u?

Comment: I am thinking sth else also. IS there anyway you can tell me what the http authentication headers should  look like when inserting subsscription? what I can do is then insert subscription via Jason through soapui using the tokens in my db

Comment: the code is same except I am inserting subscription first and then item

Comment: The code isn't the same, since you said you were printing out the results now, and your code doesn't show this. I'm trying to understand what it is doing and returning, and a cut-paste of your code (minus the URL) could help identify where the problem is. Taking this to email won't help the next person who comes along with the same problem, which is why we're trying to solve it publicly.

Comment: updated with outpout of variables I am printing in immediate window

Comment: I have another priority come up to get a barcode reader working on Glass...Unfortunately I will have to get to this once I can figure that out :) I am now stuck with launchy not working on Glass. :)