# Google Mirror API does not trust Godaddy G2 SSL certs?

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I think Google Mirror API is not trusting Go Daddy G2 SSL certs. Anyone can confirm?

Comment: That certificate should be fine. Can you amend your question to include a bit about why you think it's not being trusted?  Error messages help a lot.

Comment: I assume this is a continuation of the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529792/google-glass-not-receving-subscription-notifications

Comment: Yes. I do not see notification (http post from Google to my callbackurl...not one entry in server logs) for my subscription . I have inserted item https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/timeline/d45fcc3a-4346-453a-8783-88667a002387
 and created subscription for my timeline. no notification from Google yet. However I can use soapui and post to my callbackurl and have that code write to my glass. So I am stuck. when we got go daddy g2 ssl certs we had numerous java clkient report the issue as Java run time does not trust go daddy g2 ssl certs (the 2048 bit ke length version)

Comment: Hello Jenny Murphy. I did a very simple test. I created a timeline item (built using html with image url that has my  current call back server - Using godaddy g2 root ssl cert and then I have another item built  with image url hosted on a server using using  digicert certificate ). You know what happened? the one with  Godaddy did not show the image the other one showed the image. I have emailed u my code with my server url using godaddy g2 ssl cert. can you please confirm with your engineers? I am not sure what you use but it is a issue that java runtime does not trust by default godaddayg2ro

Comment: The certificate should be OK. Even self-signed certs will work. The probable reason you don't get the notification is because user does not take any action with this timeline item. Try to insert timeline item with "REPLY" and reply to it - this will send the notification, just inserting the item in timeline does not notify. It sends notification only if user will do something with it and if item was created by the same application. if you want to have notification about the item that have been created by any other app - then you will need to "SHARE" the item with contact created by your app.